# Running an eclipse project in command line

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, command

How would I run an eclipse project with specific methods in the command line? Like, how could I rename a method with a longer name to something shorter so that I don't have to type the whole thing in the command line? basically abbreviations

I've done this in Python, but I'm not sure how to do it in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question may not have been clear enough. Here is the solution I found though

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 1)   {
    //do a thing
    } else if (args.length == 2){
        if(args[1].toUpperCase().equals("string i'm looking for"))
            //do a thing
    } else if (args.length == 3) {
        if(args[1].equals("string1")&& args[2].equals("string2")    || args[2].equals("string1")&& args[1].equals("string2"))
            //do a thing
        }
    }
```

where I'm calling it on the args[]

Answer (score 1):

Java entry point is `main` and is not mutable like python. There is nothing like `__init__` to check in Java. When you package a Java program as a jar, you can specify the `Main-Class` in the MANIFEST. See also [Lesson: Packaging Programs in JAR Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/)